# Eclipse Oracle Hibernate StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jdbc

Getting this odd error during changeover from MySql to Oracle.  Everything worked fine until I switched over to an Oracle driver.  The autowired class SessionFactory is now failing, but with this odd String error:

```
Nov 5, 2012 4:52:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'services': Cannot create inner bean 'com.capitalone.api.socialdata.SocialDataApi#2f729e' of type [com.capitalone.api.socialdata.SocialDataApi] while setting bean property 'serviceBeans' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.capitalone.api.socialdata.SocialDataApi#2f729e': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.capitalone.api.socialdata.service.SocialDataService com.capitalone.api.socialdata.SocialDataApi.socialDataService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.capitalone.api.socialdata.service.SocialDataServiceImpl#0': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.capitalone.api.socialdata.dao.ProfileDAO com.capitalone.api.socialdata.service.SocialDataServiceImpl.profileDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.capitalone.api.socialdata.dao.ProfileDAOImpl#0': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.capitalone.api.socialdata.dao.ProfileDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 13068
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.capitalone.api.socialdata.SocialDataApi#2f729e': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.capitalone.api.socialdata.service.SocialDataService com.capitalone.api.socialdata.SocialDataApi.socialDataService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.capitalone.api.socialdata.service.SocialDataServiceImpl#0': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.capitalone.api.socialdata.dao.ProfileDAO com.capitalone.api.socialdata.service.SocialDataServiceImpl.profileDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.capitalone.api.socialdata.dao.ProfileDAOImpl#0': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.capitalone.api.socialdata.dao.ProfileDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 13068
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
```

Columns mapped in DAO files like such:

```
@Column(name="CHANNEL_NAME")
private String name;
```

jdbc.properties has these lines:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:3306:MYDB
```

.pom file has this dependency:
    
    com.oracle
    ojdbc5
    11.2.0.3

Comment: Columns are mapped using @Column annotation:       @Column(name="CHANNEL_NAME")
 private String name;
 
 @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
 private String description;

Comment: post your beans.xml file

Answer (score 0):

`Injection of autowired dependencies failed;` did you update your dependencies in all the right places?

Comment: Do you mean maven .pom file dependencies?

Comment: Spring uses injected dependencies, if you were using `MySQLDBManager` and now you're using `OracleDBManager` you need to make sure that class has changed everywhere relevant.

Answer (score 0):

@ character in jdbc.properties file seemed to be causing the String out of bounds exception:
I changed:

```
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:3306:MYDB
```

to:

```
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:oracle:thin://localhost:3306:MYDB
```